# File uploads - When should WCF vs other solutions be used

Tags: .net, wcf, file, service, streaming

A project that I am currently working on requires a WCF end point that will receive some structured data and with it one or more binary files.

The client to the service would prefer that there be no limitation to the size of these uploads but everything has a limitation.

My question is, at what point does a WCF service for uploading a file become an unsuitable solution?

To put this into some context, this is not a solution that an end user would be triggering so things like progress bars etc are not a requirement.

Thanks,
Andrew.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, Andrew.

I'm doing WCF development on a CRM software package used by some of the largest companies on the planet. I don't think there's any realistic functional limit to what WCF can handle in terms of binary uploading and downloading, but there are, of course, practical limits we've run into along the lines of client bandwidth, client and server timeouts (default is two minutes for clients), server power/storage and other issues that would/could be mitigated with some creative architecture and programming.

For instance, some of our clients have end users with laptops in 2nd world countries where the bandwidth is poor, which can trigger download/upload timeouts. The way we mitigated that was by using "chunked" uploads and downloads, meaning that if one is uploading or downloading a 500MB file, the binary is broken down into smaller chunks (1MB or 10MB) that the client and host can handle over a bad connection without timing out, iterating until the download or upload was complete. And these chunks can be adjusted on the fly depending on the "badness" of the connection. But using this method, we've download entire 1GB+ databases down to our client's devices without trouble.

We have clients using prehistoric PDAs, iPads, Android devices, etc. and all their special requirements can be mitigated (again) with some clever programming.

Better than that, I recently saw a demo of a women's clothing catalog application that used WCF to deliver content ... the speed was unbelievable. You could "spin" the pages with the flip of a finger as fast as you wanted and the app would fill in the speeding pages with product pictures and descriptions without trouble. The guy said it was the second fastest catalog application in the world - second only to ebay.